# Find a gps position on a google map

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map in my site. I enabled zoom and map moving. How to find the gps position of left upper corner that is displayed currently ?

Comment: Assuming you talk about the google maps API. Which version? Why the upper left corner of your map region? Why not simply for for `mymap.getCenter()` for the GPS location in the centre of the map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [getBounds()](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) method of the V3 API will return the bounding box data -  the co-ordinates of the SW and NE corners of the current map.

The top left (NW) corner can of course then be easily derived.